# How to align numbers with units in tables

Tags: tables, alignment, units

How can I align numbers with units in a table?
I tries with siunitx but it does not work:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption goes here.}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lS}
        \toprule
        Substance   & Amounts \\ \midrule
        A           & 1 $mL$    \\
        B           & 100 $mg$  \\
        C           & 0.5 $mg$  \\
        D           & 82 $\mu L$   \\
        E           & 0.1 $g$   \\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would do it also manually if there is a possibility, since I do write not need lots of tables.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify your formatting objective. E.g., should all numbers be aligned on their decimal markers and all units be left-aligned? Please be specific.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, the optimal outcome would be numbers aligned on decimal marker and units to the left (without having too much space between number and unit).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption goes here.}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} 
                        l 
                        S[table-format=2.1] 
                        @{\,} 
                        s[table-unit-alignment=left]
                        @{} }
        \toprule
        Substance   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Amounts} \\ 
        \midrule
        A           & 1   & \milli\liter    \\
        B           & 100 & \milli\gram  \\
        C           & 0.5 & \milli\gram  \\
        D           & 82  & \micro\liter    \\
        E           & 0.1 & \gram   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed
Thank you very much